# Missing stats from Riot DataDragon API

Tags: riot-games-api

I am attempting to use Riot's public API to create a website, but I've noticed that the crit damage field is set to 0 for all champions, yet when I look at the wiki, each champion has a set damage % set. I'm wondering if this stat is possible to retrieve in the API, or if I need to make a list manually with all their crit damage values?

[For reference. You'll see that crit and critperlevel are both set to 0](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/13.18.1/data/en_US/champion/Aatrox.json) |
[Here, however, crit damage is defined.](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Aatrox/LoL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this CDN https://cdn.merakianalytics.com/riot/lol/resources/latest/en-US/champions.json which fetches data directly from the wiki. It is even open source, if you want to check it out: https://github.com/meraki-analytics/lolstaticdata.